# How do i get the maximum or minimum value from SELECT query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, select

I have a table that holds water meter readings. Now that the table will holds millions of records month in month out, i am looking for a way to subtract the previous meter reading from the current meter reading for a particular account number and get the units consumed for the period in question

I have managed to pull out the last two entries for a particular account_number and have tried to use the MAX or MIN on a select query but it seems it only works with columns

This is the code i have

```
 SELECT (MAX(SELECT actual_reading FROM test_meter_readings
                        WHERE account_number = '23-456789T67'
                        ORDER BY timestamp_capture 
                        DESC
                        LIMIT 2)) - 
                    (MIN(SELECT actual_reading FROM test_meter_readings
                        WHERE account_number = '23-456789T67'
                        ORDER BY timestamp_capture 
                        DESC
                        LIMIT 2))
                      ''',)
```

I expect to get the difference from 2 last entries for every account in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LAG()`:

```
select (actual_reading - prev_actual_reading) as diff
from (select tmr.*,
             lag(actual_reading) over (partition by account_number order by timestamp_capture) as prev_actual_reading
      from test_meter_readings tmr
      where account_number = '23-456789T67'
     ) tmr
order by timestamp_capture desc
fetch first 1 row only;  -- or limit 1
```

EDIT:

To handle multiple accounts, you can use `row_number()` or `distinct on`.  The first method looks like this:

```
select (actual_reading - prev_actual_reading) as diff
from (select tmr.*,
             lag(actual_reading) over (partition by account_number order by timestamp_capture) as prev_actual_reading,
             row_number() over (partition by account_number order by timestamp_capture) as seqnum
      from test_meter_readings tmr
      -- where account_number = '23-456789T67'
     ) tmr
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: How then do i get the difference for every account or multiple accounts in the table at once if possible then assign the results to a different table